# Automatically create StructType from avsc file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

when reading an avro file into a spark data frame (version 1.3.0) I see people create the StructType through code.

But I don't want to hardcode the schema into my code. instead I want to read an external "AVSC" file which contains the schema and generate the StructType.

Is that possible? if yes, how?

Comment: Doesn't Spark-Avro handle that for you?

Comment: I am on spark avro 1.0.0 (because of spark 1.3.0). I get a dataframe but I need to access it like x(0) rather than x.Field

Comment: spark-avro infers schema on read, but this is very slow for my avro data which has schema with ~1000 fields, many nested.

Comment: I want to make zero record dataframe using avsc file, if any particular avro file is not found. As I have always the avsc file

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work for you:

```
val sqlType = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(yourSchema).dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a spark-avro project in git hub provided by databricks.
https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro

With this project you can read avro files without specifying any schema. The supported Spark version is sparkVersion := "1.4.1"

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
    .load("src/test/resources/episodes.avro")

df.filter("doctor > 5").write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
    .save("/tmp/output")
```

Comment: I am on spark 1.0.0 I am using spark-avro 1.0.0